# How do I sum only the unique values in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table `shipping_manifest` that `contain client_id`, `order_id`, `pallet_id` and `pallet_volume`.

In the second table `Order_header`, I have the `client_id`, `order_id`, `order_volume`. I need to calculate the `pallet_volume + the order_volume`. However, there can be multiple pallets for one order in the `shipping_manifest` table or there can be single pallet multiple times in the `shipping_manifest` table. 2 examples orders

```
CLIENT_ID ORDER_ID   PALLET_ID          PALLET_VOLUME ORDER_VOLUME
A         TESTJBDN11 373943762002480563 0.12          18
A         TESTJBDN11 373943762002480549 0.12          18
A         TESTJBDN11 H876               0.12          18
A         TESTJBDN4  EXT-5422081        0.1           0.15
A         TESTJBDN4  EXT-5422081        0.1           0.15
A         TESTJBDN4  EXT-5422081        0.1           0.15
```

The `total_pallet_volume` should be the `order_value +` the `pallet_volume` for each unique `pallet_id`

so for order `TESTJBDN11` it should be `18 + (3 * 0.12) = 18.36`
and for order `TESTJBDN4` it should be `0.15 + 0.1 = 0.25`

I have tried I have tried doing :

Example A

```
SELECT sm.client_id,sm.order_id,sm.pallet_id, sm.pallet_volume,oh.order_volume,SUM(sm.pallet_volume)+oh.order_volume as "total_pallet_volume"
    FROM Shipping_Manifest sm
         LEFT JOIN order_header oh ON oh.order_id = sm.order_id AND oh.client_id = sm.client_id
    WHERE sm.client_id = 'A' AND
        sm.ORDER_ID = 'TESTJBDN4'
        GROUP BY sm.client_id, sm.order_id,sm.pallet_id, sm.pallet_volume, oh.order_volume;
```

Example B:

```
select sm.client_id,sm.order_id, sm.pallet_volume,oh.order_volume,
(select sum(sm.pallet_volume )+( oh.order_volume) 
    from Shipping_Manifest sm
         left join order_header oh on oh.order_id = sm.order_id and oh.client_id = sm.client_id
    WHERE sm.client_id = 'A' and
        sm.ORDER_ID = 'TESTJBDN11'
        group by sm.pallet_volume,oh.order_volume) AS "total_pallet_volume"
        from Shipping_Manifest sm
        left join order_header oh on oh.order_id = sm.order_id and oh.client_id = sm.client_id
WHERE sm.client_id = 'A' and
sm.ORDER_ID = 'TESTJBDN11';
```

Example C:

```
SELECT sm.client_id,sm.order_id,sm.pallet_id, sm.pallet_volume,oh.order_volume,sm.pallet_volume +oh.order_volume as "total_pallet_volume"
    FROM Shipping_Manifest sm
         LEFT JOIN order_header oh ON oh.order_id = sm.order_id AND oh.client_id = sm.client_id
    WHERE sm.client_id = 'A' AND
        sm.ORDER_ID IN ('TESTJBDN11','TESTJBDN4')
        GROUP BY sm.client_id, sm.order_id, sm.pallet_id, sm.pallet_volume, oh.order_volume, 
sm.pallet_volume +oh.order_volume;
```

so for order `TESTJBDN11` it should be `18 + (3 * 0.12) = 18.36`

using select Example A - actual output is `18.12`

using select Example B - actual output is `18.36` (which is correct but doesn't work for the other scenario)

using select Example C - actual output is `18.12`

and for order `TESTJBDN4` it should be `0.15 + 0.1 = 0.25`

using select Example A - actual output is  `0.45`

using select Example B - actual output is  `0.45`

using select Example C - actual output is  `0.25` (which is correct but doesn't work for the other scenario)

I need one statement that will work for both orders as there are multiple orders in the tables.

Comment: please show your sample data per table, not grouped together, since several answers are based upon the assumption that you have duplicates rows in `Shipping_Manifest`. This needs to be clarified obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, too:

> ```
> select * from shipping_manifest
> ```
>
> ```
> CLIENT_ID | ORDER_ID   | PALLET_ID          | PALLET_VOLUME | ORDER_VOLUME
> :-------- | :--------- | :----------------- | ------------: | -----------:
> A         | TESTJBDN11 | 373943762002480563 |           .12 |           18
> A         | TESTJBDN11 | 373943762002480549 |           .12 |           18
> A         | TESTJBDN11 | H876               |           .12 |           18
> A         | TESTJBDN4  | EXT-5422081        |            .1 |          .15
> A         | TESTJBDN4  | EXT-5422081        |            .1 |          .15
> A         | TESTJBDN4  | EXT-5422081        |            .1 |          .15
> ```

```
select
 client_id, order_id, pallet_id, pallet_volume, order_volume,
 SUM(pallet_volume) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) + SUM(distinct order_volume) as TOTAL 
from yourt_table where your_coinditions -- replace your clause
 group by client_id, order_id, pallet_id,pallet_volume, order_volume
```

> ```
> CLIENT_ID | ORDER_ID   | PALLET_ID          | PALLET_VOLUME | ORDER_VOLUME | TOTAL
> :-------- | :--------- | :----------------- | ------------: | -----------: | ---------:
> A         | TESTJBDN11 | 373943762002480549 |           .12 |           18 |      18.36
> A         | TESTJBDN11 | 373943762002480563 |           .12 |           18 |      18.36
> A         | TESTJBDN11 | H876               |           .12 |           18 |      18.36
> A         | TESTJBDN4  | EXT-5422081        |            .1 |          .15 |        .25
> ```

[Compiled](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=82f2d692f00c43130ee8d17a41beae6d)

Answer (score 0):

So basically if your shipping_manifest table [shipping_manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CuiE.png) and order_header [order_header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT0bp.png) looks like this:

You can run the following query:

```
select distinct s.client_id, s.order_id, pallet_id, pallet_volume * s.count_unique_pallet_id + s2.order_volumne as result
from shipping_manifest o left join (
SELECT  a.client_id, a.order_id, count(distinct a.pallet_id) as count_unique_pallet_id
from shipping_manifest a
group by a.client_id, a.order_id) s
on o.client_id = s.client_id and o.order_id = s.order_id
left join (select client_id, order_id, order_volumne from order_header) s2
on o.client_id = s2.client_id and o.order_id = s2.order_id
```

It gives the following result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/241w9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.

This approach addresses two edge cases: the case where there are no pallets but there is an order volume (the `LEFT JOIN`) and the case where there are different values for the same pallet (using `MAX(pallet_volume)`). It may be that neither of these cases are possible, but I always like belt-and-suspenders protection.

The setup:

```
create table shipping_manifest(
  manifest_id integer,
  client_id varchar2(20),
  order_id varchar2(20),
  pallet_id varchar2(20),
  pallet_volume number
);
create table order_header(
  client_id varchar2(20),
  order_id varchar2(20),
  order_volume number
);
insert into order_header values('A','TESTJBDN11', 18);
insert into order_header values('A','TESTJBDN4', 0.15);
insert into shipping_manifest values (1,'A','TESTJBDN11','373943762002480563', 0.12);
insert into shipping_manifest values (2,'A','TESTJBDN11','373943762002480549', 0.12);
insert into shipping_manifest values (3,'A','TESTJBDN11','H876', 0.12);
insert into shipping_manifest values (4,'A','TESTJBDN4','EXT-5422081', 0.1);
insert into shipping_manifest values (5,'A','TESTJBDN4','EXT-5422081', 0.1);
insert into shipping_manifest values (6,'A','TESTJBDN4','EXT-5422081', 0.1);
COMMIT;
```

The query:

```
with pallets as(
  select client_id, order_id, pallet_id, max(pallet_volume) as max_pallet_volume
    from shipping_manifest sm
    group by client_id, order_id, pallet_id
)
select oh.client_id, oh.order_id, oh.order_volume + sum(p.max_pallet_volume) volume
from order_header oh
left join pallets p on p.client_id = oh.client_id and p.order_id = oh.order_id
group by oh.client_id, oh.order_id, order_volume;
```